# Custom Post Type Conditional - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a conditional query for a custom post type. I need it to be relevant to a specific post though. So for example, I have the current code which works for ALL projects:

```
<?php if ('project' == get_post_type() ) {  ?> 
// Get content 
<?php } ?>
```

However, I need to be able to specify a certain project with ID 75. Is this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `get_the_ID()` function inside the LOOP:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

```
<?php if ('project' == get_post_type() && get_the_ID() == 75) {  ?> 
// Get content 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use $post global variable for specific custom post.

`<?php if($post->post_type == 'project' && $post->ID == '75') : ?>
      //Get Content
<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
if($post->post_type == 'type your post type here' ) : 
  //Get Content
```

endif;

this is working...

Comment: Could you explain why?